# Criar um objeto com parâmetros fortes em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parâmetros

Eu preciso criar um objeto a partir somente de um botão.

Não passo nada para o método, só o chamo através do botão.

Todos os dados que preciso tenho acesso na action do controller que estou usando.

Porém não consigo inserir no banco de dados, por conta do Strong Parameters.

Já tentei tanta solução que nem sei mais o que estou fazendo. :/

Aqui eu tento criar um novo token os dados que gerei na action

```
@token = Token.new(duration: duration, token: token, check: false, user_id: current_user.id)
```

Essa é a parte do strong parameters

```
def token_params
      params.require(:token).permit(:duration, :token, :check, :user_id, :gym_id)
    end
```

E quando verifico os parâmetros que passei para a action.
Ex.: {"utf8"=>"✓" .... }
A Hash "token" não  vem junto, talvez isso seja óbvio pois não estou enviando nada, além do commit do botão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você realmente não vai precisar de strong params nesse caso. Creio que somente mudando o `new` para o `create` vai resolver seu problema em sua `action`.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo! ^^